# Динамическая диспетчеризация методов

Tags: java

```
class A {
    void callme() {
        System.out.println("   callme() из класса А");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void callme() {
        System.out.println("   callme() из класса B");
    }
}

class C extends A {
    void callme() {
        System.out.println("   callme() из класса C");
    }
}

class Dispatch {
    public static void main(Strin args []) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new C();

        A r; // <--

        r=a;
        r.callme();

        r=b;
        r.callme();

        r=c;
        r.callme();
    }
}
```

Вопрос: Для чего в строке, отмеченной стрелкой, ссылаться именно на объект `А`?

Comment: Уточните какие именно из ваших ожиданий сей код не оправдывает.

Comment: я не совсем могу понять, почему объявляется ссылка на объект А. а затем повторно на каждый объект АВС, для чего объявляется А r?

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно присвоить объекты типа `A`, `B`, `C` одной переменной. Значит, эта переменная должна иметь тип, являющийся общим предком этих типов. Таких типов два: `A` и `Object`.

Но если вы хотите при этом вызывать метод `callme`, то `Object` не подходит, в нём этот метод не определён. А `A` подходит, в нём определён метод `callme` (который потом перекрывается в производных классах).

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю,  поскольку в каждом подклассе переопределяется метод callme(), необходимо создать ссылку на объект суперкласса А r, а затем по переменной r  сослаться на конкретные объекты типа ABC вызвать метод callme()?

Comment: @Ya16: Смотрите. `A r` объявляет ссылку на объект класса `A` _или любого из производных_. То есть, `r` может ссылаться на объект классов `A`, `B` или `C`. Затем, по вызову `callme` вызывается виртуальный метод `callme`, который перегружен в классах `B` и `C` (а значит, будет вызвана именно реализация, определённая в этих классах).

Answer (score 2):

Классы `B` и `C` - это подклассы суперкласса `A`. В каждом подклассе переопределен метод `callme()`. Далее с помощью принципов полиморфизма используется вызов этого самого метода у каждого подкласса. Но дело в том, что вызывается именно переопределенный метод.

P.S:
Видимо вы не поняли что такое полиморфизм,или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 1):

Сей код демонстрирует возможности использования унаследованных классов.

1. Изначально у вас есть переменная типа `A`.
2. И классы `B` и `C` наследующие/расширяющие класс `A`.
3. Т.к. классы `B` и `C` расширяют `A` любой переменной типа `A` можно присвоить ссылку на объекты типа `B` и `C`, кроме собственно `A` и объектов типа `Object`.
4. При этом из-за динамического определения типа класса во время исполнения программы вызов метода `callme()` будет разным во всех случаях. Он будет вызываться у конкретного класса, экземпляр коего присвоен переменной `r`

При этом, если бы переменная `r` была типа `B` или `C` то ей можно было бы присвоить, соответственно, только объекты типа `B` или `C`.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения!